# Platform Independent Full-screen JFrame w/ Specified Resolution?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, fullscreen

I am try to write a JFrame App which I want fullscreen (and by this I do not mean maximized), however the Application UI is very small (about 500x600) is there a possible way I could set the resolution of a fullscreen JFrame to 1024x768 that will work on Linux and Windows?
I was simply using this code:

```
setUndecorated(true);
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
```

However I could not find a way to modify the resolution and it still displays the task panel.

I am developing in eclipse on Linux Mint 14 KDE.
Thanks in advance!

*EDIT*
: I got a little further using this code:

```
                setUndecorated( true );
                setResizable( false );
                setAlwaysOnTop( true );
                setVisible( true );
                GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(1024, 768, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
                vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                vc.setFullScreenWindow(this);
                if (dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()){
                    try{
                        vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
```

that code was inside the contructor of my class that extends JFrame. However it does not change the resolution, it just runs at default 1080p.

Answer (score 1):

> is there a possible way I could set the resolution of a fullscreen
>   JFrame to 1024x768 that will work on Linux and Windows.

If you want your `JFrame` to be shown on entire screen then you can use this one:

```
setUndecorated(true);
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
toFront();
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Full Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/) for full details, it take special note of [Display Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/displaymode.html)

Comment: This is the best way to test and (if available) set `1024x768` mode.

Comment: I edited the question with my attempt at that tutorial, but it doesn't change the resolution :( any ideas?

Comment: @LukeSilver My "guess" is that the display mode is supported. From the tutorial *"When choosing a display mode for your application, you may want to keep a list of preferred display modes, then choose the best one from the list of available display modes...As a fallback, if the display mode you desire is not available, you may want to simply run in windowed mode at a fixed size."* ... I'll see if I can have play some time today ;)